# How to create a sequential work flow?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have created a sequential workflow using sharepoint server sequential workflow template and infopath forms.  I have created a initiation form using infopath for taking assignee comments etc.  If I gave single user it is working fine.

My problem is I need to assign this workflow for 3 or more than 3 users.

For example I have users X,Y and Z. First I will create a task for X. After completing that task by X I need to create another task for Y and so on up to Z. How can I achieve this? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you would normally use a Replicator activity (and initialize it with an array containing the login names/other IDs of the three users X, Y, Z). Then you set the replicator to execute sequentially.